# Using Infinispan 6 on Websphere 8.5 throws no class found for CacheStoreConfigurationBuilder

Tags: hibernate, caching, jboss, websphere, infinispan

I have integrated Infinispan 2nd level caching to our product. It works fine with the following properties on Weblogic 12c server.

```
    <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.infinispan.cfg">infinispan-config.xml</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"> InfinispanRegionFactory </prop>
    <prop key="hibernate.session_factory_name">SessionFactories/infinispan</prop>
```

But when I try to deploy the same EAR on Websphere 8.5, it throws me the following exception

Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: Unable to start region factory
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.start(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:340)
    at com.nucleus.finnone.tbs.cache.CustomInfinispanRegionFactory.start(CustomInfinispanRegionFactory.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.(CacheImpl.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:251)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/infinispan/configuration/cache/CacheStoreConfigurationBuilder
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.(ParserRegistry.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.createCacheManager(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.start(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:323)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.infinispan.configuration.cache.CacheStoreConfigurationBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:198)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:113)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)

I tried to lookup that particular class **"CacheStoreConfigurationBuilder"** but it was available in Infinispan-core 5.* versions and is not there in the later versions, I am using Infinispan 6.* along with Spring 4 and Hibernate 4.3.*

I can't seem to understand why it is looking for that class only in websphere and not on Weblogic. Is there any particular setting\property that I am missing out here?

**UPDATE 1**   It turns out, for building configuration, A class called ParserRegistry(org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry) is called, which prepares a collection of ConfigurationParsers(in the same package). The list of the configuration parsers is the same on both the servers,
[class org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.configuration.JdbcStoreConfigurationParser60
 class org.infinispan.loaders.jpa.configuration.JpaCacheStoreConfigurationParser53
 class org.infinispan.loaders.jpa.configuration.JpaCacheStoreConfigurationParser60
 class org.infinispan.persistence.leveldb.configuration.LevelDBStoreConfigurationParser60
 class org.infinispan.persistence.remote.configuration.RemoteStoreConfigurationParser60
 class org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.Parser60]

but when it tries to ".newInstance()" for "**JpaCacheStoreConfigurationParser53"**, it gives a class(def) not found exception and a "catch(Throwable t)" occurs in the start() function of the InfinispanRegionFactory.

Although, on weblogic12c server, it simply gets the instance of that parser and moves on.

Comment: Strange, I'd check the EAR to see whether there are multiple versions of same jars somehow, and also check if Websphere ships any Infinispan and/or Hibernate jars already. Also check for other deployments in that Websphere server. Also check the configuration file, whether the versions defined there match the Infinispan version. I'd also check what your `com.nucleus.finnone.tbs.cache.CustomInfinispanRegionFactory` class does

Comment: Hey, Thanks @GalderZamarreño,
I've tried all that. Ultimately, I sat down to debug the InfinispanRegionFactory class on both the servers. Kindly refer to my Update on the question

Comment: Could it be the case that in Websphere, somewhere in the parsing process, it starts to look for an implementation of "CacheStoreConfigurationBuilder" but isn't able to find one?

Comment: You seem to have a JPA persistence store jar somewhere in the classpath, otherwise the parser registry would not find it. In fact, you shouldn't need any persistence stores that are listed there for a Hibernate 2LC application.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, has anyone found any solution for this.